# 9-patch buttons not displayed correctly

Tags: android, button

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/making-prettier-buttons-in-android-xml-rolloverselection-focus-effects-9patch-images-and-transparency/) to make some nicer buttons for Android, I also took the example 9-patch button from that site. It is this one: [image]

But as you can see in the following image, my buttons are not displayed correctly.

[image]

Here is the code of the "4 x 4" button:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="starteSpiel"
        android:text="   4 x 4   "
        android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

And here is my button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"
  android:state_pressed="false"
  android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
<item android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
```

Where is the error? The buttons should look like the ones in the [tutorial](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/making-prettier-buttons-in-android-xml-rolloverselection-focus-effects-9patch-images-and-transparency/).

Comment: You may need to save it as wtiVz.9.png file extension.

Comment: Out of curiousity why are you using a selector if your using the same image for every state?

Comment: Testing purposes. I created the other images after I solved this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to simplify your code by setting directly the `@drawable/button_normal` in `Button/@android:brackground`

By reading your code, I understand that you renamed `button.9.png` (file name in the tutorial) to `button_normal.9.png`- is that right ?